# Worklight keeps HTTP request active when user is logged out

Tags: http, authentication, ibm-mobilefirst

I have an issue with Worklight 6.1. I will describe the scenario below:

User logs in the app and a new session is created for him. Then he stays inactive for some time until the session times out. When clicking on a button, an HTTP request is performed towards an HTTP adapter. However the Worklight server (Liberty) sees that there is no active session for this user and returns the appropriate  response that the user is logged out and the user is redirected to the login page. This is correct up to here.

When the user logs in again and is redirected to the landing page, the previous request seems to have been cached and is performed resulting in an error as the necessary information is not yet available. How can I prevent this request from occruring when the user re logs in?

Thank you.

Comment: What are these pages? In an app? A Mobile Web App?

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible to prevent the original request from re-sending after authentication.
The logic of the authentication and the logic of the application are separated and the result of a successful login will be the invocation of the original failed invocation.

What you can do is add to the adapter procedure implementation the logic that makes sure all the information is available, and if not - send an empty response to the client and in the client do whatever you want to do when the data is missing.
This should be done for all the procedures that rely on the session state.